# Which Dihedral Groups are $\text{CI}$-Groups?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $D_{n}$ denotes the dihedral group of order $2n$. Firstly, for self-referencing of the question, I give some definitions which are standard.

Let $G$ be a finite group. A subset $S$ of group $G$ is called a Cayley subset if $1_G \notin S$ and $S = S^{−1}:=\{s^{−1} | s ∈ S\}$, and the Cayley graph of $G$ with respect to $S$ is the graph $Cay(G, S)$ with vertex set $G$ and with $x$ and $y$ adjacent if and only if $yx^{−1}\in S$. Each element $σ\in Aut(G)$ induces an isomorphism from $Cay(G, S)$ to $Cay(G,S^σ)$, and $Cay(G, S)$ is called a $\text{CI}$-graph of $G$ if, whenever $Cay(G,S)\cong Cay(G,T)$, there is an element $σ\in Aut(G)$ such that $S^σ =T$ ($\text{CI}$ stands for Cayley Isomorphism). Note that $Cay(G,S)$ is a regular graph of valency $|S|$. Thus $G$ is an $m$-$\text{CI}$-group if all Cayley graphs for $G$ of valency at most $m$ are $\text{CI}$-graphs, and further we say that a finite group $G$ is a $\text{CI}$-group if $G$ is a $|G|$-$\text{CI}$-group,[The link of paper for more details](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0195669898902918).

It is well known that (Babai-1978), the dihedral group $D_p$, $p$ a prime number, is $\text{CI}$-group. Also, it is shown (Haipeng Qu-1997) that the dihedral group $D_k$ is $\{1,2,3\}$-$\text{CI}$-group if and only if $2\nmid k$.

I am interested in to know that, are there any further results about the below question:

For which values of $n$ and $m$, we know that the dihedral group $D_{n}$ is $m$-$\text{CI}$-group?

Thanks for any answers.

Comment: Judging by your question, I think that you are already familiar with all the relevant literature. There is a paper by Li, Lu and Palfy that identifies a set of groups that contains all unknown CI-groups (but possibly some others too), but it does not specifically address the $m$-CI property.

Comment: @Prof. Royle, thanks for your helpful comment. Actually, I did a deep search about this topic, but always there are some points which professionals know them, but amateurs do not know them.